# Best way to stream mp3s from java/c++ server to html5?

Tags: java, html, mp3, rtp, html5-audio

I am looking into streaming mp3s from a java (preferably) or c++ server to an html5 browser on another computer.

I know html5 (depending on the browser) supports rtp, so if possible, that would be the best way to proceed.

In terms of the server side however, I am stuck. Are there any Java libraries that would enable mp3 streaming via rtp? I have looked at live555 for c++, but it seems to be a little too heavy for what I am looking for.

Or am I approaching this whole thing wrong. Basically I am looking to create a program where users can point to mp3 files on their computers/other users can open a webpage and stream these mp3 files from there.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to stream MP3 over RTP instead of e.g. HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these Java RTP implementations:

1. [java.net.RTP](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/report.html)
2. [RTP Java Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibrtp/)
3. [jlibrtp](https://wiki.cs.columbia.edu:8443/display/~hgs/jlibrtp+-+Java+RTP+Library)